# How to space grids linearly for log scale axis in Matplotlibs?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

In matplot lib, I want to space out the grids in a linearly spaced order, while the axis scale is logarithmic.

What I  want is this: [image]

instead of:
[image]

The code  so far is this:

```
ax.grid(True,  which="major", ls="-")
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:.8f}'))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:.8f}'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set the major ticks at the desired positions. Either simply `ticks=[2**i for i in range(30]` or the more elaborate ticks from the example (these will be close to being evenly-spaced, but not fully). Optionally, the numbers can be displayed with a thousands-separator. The minor ticks that are automatically added by the log scale look very confusing and can be removed.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator, StrMethodFormatter, NullFormatter, NullLocator

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.exp(10+np.random.normal(0.01, 0.6, 1000).cumsum()))
ax.grid(True,  which="major", ls="-")
ax.set_yscale('log')
ticks = [j * k for j in (1, 1000, 1000000) for k in [3, 6, 12] + [25*2**i for i in range(7)]   ]
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(ticks))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(NullLocator())
#ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())
ax.set_ylim(ymin=2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thanks. How did you derive the logic for ticks?

Comment: Just trying out a few formulas and fiddling until hitting something similar as the example.